# Mac scroll up and down

Tags: mac, scrolling

To scroll down and up in a browser and many applications I know two ways. We can use the arrow keys for small increments and option and arrow keys to bigger ones. Do you know any middle option? I mean some key shortcuts that could scroll more than the arrow keys alone but less than option and arrow.

Comment: Do you not have a scroll wheel on your mouse? And on a trackpad a two finger scroll does the same.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I would like a solution only with the keyboard as it is something that I do very frequently. But perhaps it is not possible?

Comment: Command UP/DOWN (arrow keys) go to top and bottom of the document. FN Up/Down go page up and page down if you don't have those keys already. Look in "Document Shortcuts" here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236